# SonarQube runner in sbt: findbugs, scalastyle

Tags: scala, sbt, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube5.1

I am trying to setup the SunarQube runner as an sbt task. So far I have managed to generate reports for Scoverage only.

I am running the `findbugs` task independently, which generated a report.xml, but the sonar runner doesn't pick it up. Relevant settings I pass to the sonar runner:

```
  "sonar.dynamicAnalysis" -> "reuseReports",
  "sonar.scoverage.reportPath" -> s"${crossTarget.value}/scoverage-report/scoverage.xml",
  "sonar.findbugs.reportPath" -> s"${crossTarget.value}/findbugs/report.xml",
```

Is there another setting I should know? Is there a complete listing of all the settings I can use in Sonar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not going to be able to pick up that FindBugs report; the [FindBugs plugin](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/FindBugs+Plugin) runs the tool itself, based on the [rules](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Rules) configured in the [profile](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Quality+Profiles) in use.

Comment: I haven't been able to get sonar to run findbugs on my Scala code/bytecode. Is there any magic switch to make it work, or am I just out of luck?

Comment: The FindBugs plugin is tied to the Java language. If you want to analyze Scala code using Java rules, you'll have to edit the sonar.java.file.suffixes to include your Scala extension(s).

Comment: That doesn't seem to work very well. Is there perhaps some API or HTTP interface that I can use to submit a report directly? If so, where can I find documentation? Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at the AndroidLint plugin, which does this sort of thing. Note that you'll also need to register the Scala language if you don't already have on board a plugin that does that.

Comment: BTW, you've morphed this question through comments twice and I've done my best to be helpful each time. Maybe you could accept my answer?